# How do I replace my appsettings.json at build or publish?

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-configuration

During development, I am using SQL Server locally. However when I want to publish, I have to go to my network share and copy it (overwriting my file) and then build/publish.

Is there a way I can automate this by copying the file from

```
\\Network\IT\ProjectName\appsettings.json
```

to `my project directory\appsettings.json`

Comment: You don't - you create an environment specific file that overrides some settings in any previous configured values. Have you [checked the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.10)?

Comment: the problem is people on my team use a different hostname when they are working on the same project and it gets pushed to the repo. If we can do this then it would help our workflow.

Comment: The hostname doesn't affect anything. You can even use host-specific files as long as you load them after the config you want to override. Have you check the docs? `appsettings.json` is just a JSON file that's used by default. After that you can load environment -specific files (development, production, staging), environment variables, or even use the env variable names to construct the file names to load. This means you could use the host name as part of the settings file too